# Disable links within wordpress comments for no role users

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, comments

We recently decided to disable all links that were active within the comments, but we want the links posted by our registered users (contributor, editor, author) to remain active.

We added this function to functions.php but it has disabled all links in comments, including those posted by our registered users.

```
add_filter ('pre_comment_content', 'wp_specialchars'); // disable HTML in comments
remove_filter ('comment_text', 'make_clickable', 9); // autolinks in comments
```

How can we disable all links, leaving only the links of our contributor, editor, author active?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom function to strip the  tags if the author's role is not in the allowed roles you set.

```
add_filter ('pre_comment_content', 'custom_comments_links'); 

function custom_comments_links($comment_content){
   global $authordata;

   $allowed_roles = array ( 'contributor', 'editor', 'author');
   if(!array_intersect($authordata->roles, $allowed_roles)){
       $comment_content = strip_tags($comment_content, '<p><div><span>');
   }
   return $comment_content;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but it didn't work :(

I wanted the links placed in the comment body by the contributors, editor or author to stay there (active) and the new ones to continue showing the active links. 

And for the rest of the comments, the links would be inactive (appearing but not clickable) and new ones inserted would not become clickable links.